# How can twitter hashtag counts go down?

Tags: twitter, statistics, social-networking, hashtag

I noticed that twitter is changing the count for hashtags on a trending topic quite dramatically, but surely the count can only go up? The #piggate count was at over 400k last night and today it was at 340k and now down to 310k. Is there a conspiracy here to reduce the impact on the British PM? I'm interested if there is a technical reason it could reduce other than tweets being deleted?

Comment: The algorithm that twitter uses to calculate the amount of used hashtags is not disclosed. A wild guess would suggest that it is the amount of used hashtags in the past x days and not from the start. This makes sense because  else some popular hashtags would stay on top of the trending list indefinitly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is very possible, as far as "conspiracy" on Twitter's part is doubtful. However, other individuals most probable.

With Twitter you have the option to report certain tweets and even accounts that are in violation of [Twitter Rules](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18311) and [Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/tos) explained clearly in [How to report Violations](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15789).

Looking briefly at the [#piggate](https://twitter.com/hashtag/piggate?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Ehashtag) page on Twitter, I don't doubt many of these can get reported on a daily basis.

Another possible theory, depending how you obtained that count, people are actually deleting their tweets. If you delete a tweet that you might be embarrassed about, it might no longer display, but the count takes a while for it to be removed. This is more of a bug that occurs after mass deletion of tweets.

In the end it could be either 1) Tweets being reported, or 2) Tweets being deleted, even a combination of the two. Here's a [topic](http://www.inquisitr.com/2351405/twitter-suspends-ashley-madison-leak-account-that-published-names-photos-and-employers-of-ashley-madison-users/) that justifies the first case, if enough people are reporting Tweets they will be removed.

Comment: but to have a drop of 350,000 tweets in the space of 24 hours seems steep surely?

Comment: but yes, thanks for the answer anyway :) People deleting them seems reasonable to an extent thought it seems like something GCHQ or some other government agency might have a script to report lots of tweets if they damage the reputation of the UK PM. People might argue that's conspiratorial, but surely Snowden has taught us something...

Comment: I don't doubt that the drop has had an influence from government agency, but to say that with 100% is more of hearsay without valid proof. Such a drastic change (~90k) in one day is highly unlikely to be done by users.

Comment: yeah I didn't update my question before, but actually it went right down to 75,000 tweets in just under 2 days from nearly 500,000. Anyway, I don't suppose anyone else will answer so I'll award the points soon :)

Comment: O that is insane, do you have proof of numbers saved somewhere, I'd be interested in seeing the change.

Comment: I wish I screenshot it, at the time I was quite alarmed but thought perhaps I didn't understand the system of trending and hashtag logging, hence why I posed the question here! I'll see if I can find anything online recording it :)

Comment: so does that mean that twitter just removed them from the count so as to drive it out of the trending section?

Comment: No that's not cumulative, it's what's going on right then. That spike that you see on the 19th-20th the total activity for that day only.